# InstallShieldExpress launching JScript custom action: is it possible to access the variable [INSTALLDIR]

Tags: javascript, installshield

I am discovering InstallShield Express (2011 version 17). Nice enough, it is possible to configure some custom actions. Namely, I can launch JScript scripts(seems to be a Javascript dialect, files ending in *.js).

My script does some regedit stuffs, launches msiexec for installing MSXML, and executes an exe for installing security-dongle drivers... The overall is rather nice... But I am feeding the `WScript.Shell` commands **with hard coded paths**. *I never like that*.

So as to be smarter, I would like to know if the InstallShield Express property [INSTALLDIR] could be accessed by some sort of InstallShieldObject inside the *.js

so as I could write something like:

```
function doInstall()
{
    installDir = InstallShieldObject.INSTALLDIR // <= this is what I'd like to do
    var comandUpdateRegistry = "regedit /s" + installDir + "registryScript.reg"

    oShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" );
    oShell.Run( updateRegistryScriptCommand );

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand that what you are doing violates several best practices?  If you do, or you don't care,  then take a look at the Session object.

[Session Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Session.Property("MYPROP" )  Get; Set;

If you didn't know and/or you do care, then realize that 1) Script custom actions are fragile and 2) MSI is declarative not imperative.  You shouldn't reinvent the wheel with a custom action soemthing that can be done natively using the [Registry table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In the context of InstallShield, you can right click import a Reg file into the registry table and MSI will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: It is just the first time I use InstallShield for packaging. I do care about good practice. Thanx for highlighting them to me. Thanx for pointing me the import of reg file. I will try again the custom action launch "exe" with commands for the external child MSI.

Comment: MSI's can't call MSI's without violating best practices.  Since you are using InstallShield you want to look into "Setup Prerequisites".

Comment: thx, I have added the condition "Find msiexec in Windows subfolders" as a requirement.